# iOS image sizes for general purpose images (not navigation and tool bar)

Tags: ios

For the navigation bar and toolbar icons, the sizes are specified as 22x22, 44x44 and 66x66. But what if I want to have an icon on my screen that's not on the navigation bar or on the toolbar? For example, a circular upload photo button on a registration page, that is around 100 x 100. So, an image of a camera inside a regular button.

1. Are there any guidelines around how large these images need to be?
2. Assuming a 100x100 version looks right on iPhone 6, what are the sizes I need to add in my Assets.xcassets? 50x50, 100x100, and 200x200?
3. Do these custom images get scaled depending on the screen size?

Comment: Better yet, whenever possible, don't use bitmap icons. Use vector fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer 1:

Yes. Apple makes guidelines for everything. ;-) You can have a look at the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/). It contains some useful tips for designing your app.

It's a really long document and I haven't found information about the minimum size of images. But If your images are tappable, they should be at least 44x44 pt (not necessarily pixels; see "Answer 2") large.

> Provide ample spacing for interactive elements. Try to maintain a minimum tappable area of 44pt x 44pt for all controls.
>
> **Source:** [iOS Human Interface Guidelines -> Visual Design -> Layout](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/layout/)

### Answer 2:

iOS uses 3 different sizes for images: @1x (which you usually don't put in the file-name), @2x and @3x

The @1x-images should have the same number of pixels in width and height as you are using in the interface builder (pt; points).

The iPhone 6 has a retina display, so it uses @2x. This is twice the resolution of @1x. So if your @2x-image has 100x100 pixels, the @1x-version needs to have 50x50 pixels.

@3x is NOT twice the size of @2x. It's the triple size of @1x. So in your example, you would need 150x150 pixels.

The [Technote QA1686](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html) contains some more information about the different resolutions.

### Answer 3:

Yes. But especially on older devices and when you are using many images, the performance will be better, if you provide images of the correct size.

---

This image (a screenshot of the assets catalog, Apple shows in the technote I mentioned), illustrates the calculation of the image-sizes based on the size (in pt) used in the interface builder:

[image: screenshot]